# react-native-navigation and redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

How to write the redux data-flow using react-native-navigation?
this is my codes:

```
- Navigation.registerComponent('Scan', () => props => (   <Provider
  store={store}>
      <ScanScreen {...props} />   </Provider> ))
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **registerComponentWithRedux** from react-native-navigation instead of **registerComponent**

And you do not need to manually wrap your component in Provider.

Please refer below snippet for integration:

```
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux(
    "your_route_name",
    () => YourScreenComponent,
    Provider,
    store
);
```

In above code snippet:

1. You will get **Provider** from : import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
2. **store** which you with configure using redux **configureStore**
   method